# View from virtual camera in uwsim

Tags: ros, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to get a view of an object from virtual camera in robot in uwsim?There is not much documentation for uwsim. So how to learn using it . Should i try to understand its coding first because that also requires a lot of time , reading its sources , its libraries, osg, various classes in osg, etc ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189819/view-from-virtual-camera-in-uwsim/) by [Mind_hunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/19892/mind_hunter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2014-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Documentation is a pending issue in UWSim, but for installation and first steps you can check the [wiki](http://www.irs.uji.es/uwsim/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) . In the case of virtual cameras you can access to them pressing "c" on uwsim window or check the topics where they are published (stated on xml scene config file), for instance in cirs.xml is "/uwsim/camera1"

---

Originally posted by [Javier Perez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3430/javier-perez/) with karma: 486 on 2014-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mind_hunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/19892/mind_hunter/) on 2014-08-12**:
thanksss...